# Concatenate two columns in eloquent where clause in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, lumen

In my database, `country_code` and `phone_number` are two different fields. The user is entering a single string containing country code and phone number to login. In order to validate this, I have to concatenate the columns `country_code` and `phone_number` in the eloquent where clause.

Can someone tell me how to do this ? I am giving my query below.

```
$user  = self::where('phone_number', '=', $username)->get()->first();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use whereRaw with a raw SQL expression and bind the parameters with the second argument.

```
whereRaw("CONCAT(`country_code`, `phone_number`) = ?", [$username]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code:

```
$user = self::whereRaw("CONCAT_WS(' ',`country_code`, `phone_number`) = ? ",  [$username])->get()->first();
```

The first argument should be the gluing piece.

Comment: Do not ever put a user sourced variable in a raw expression!  This opens it up to SQL injection.

Comment: Right, my bad out there.